# How to spoof Android device in VM?

Tags: applications

Trying to learn making bots on Android.

I need to be able to make a VM with an Android and spoof any device info to make bot less detectable as their should be few instances.
Preferably something that wouldn't require any restarting or maybe could spoof only info for one app.